# jQuery @ operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

So I have someone else's old code that I am trying to restore. I am not too familiar with jQuery, but what does the `@` operator specify?

The code is:

```
v_button_format = $('#' + v_form_id).find('input[@name=button_format]').val();
v_content_type = $('#' + v_form_id).find('input[@name=content_type]').val();
```

I am using jQuery 1.3 and it's throwing an "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@name=button_format]" error. Is there a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an attribute selector.

The `@` is an XPath-ism that is no longer used in jQuery.
In addition, newer versions of jQuery require the attribute value to be in quotes.

Therefore, you should write

```
$('#' + v_form_id).find('input[name="content_type"]').val();
```

Comment: is the @ operator backwards compatible with the current jQuery?

Comment: Little off topic, but for such thing isn't it better to use `document.getElementsByName`?

Comment: @SLaks: It's not required. Sizzle's matches selector: `expr = expr.replace(/\=\s*([^'"\]]*)\s*\]/g, "='$1']");` does work without them - in fact that's the code to add them.

Comment: @Shadow: I would always use jQuery, internally is uses `getElementsByName` if it available on the clients browser! jQuery is a intuitive wrapper for broken or not supported browser features, for example CSS3 or memory holes in IE!

Comment: @powtac#2: Are you sure? That's quite a clever optimization.

Comment: @powtac: I was talking about the quotes, I'm sorry. The `@` does not work anymore indeed.

Comment: @Shadow When you search for `getElementsByName` you will find it exactly twice in the "find::name" method http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js I think jQuery is very effective in using the most efficient available method.

Comment: @pow OK fair enough. Thanks! Regarding `@` it's clear that it's no longer supported and throw the error our OP got.

Answer (score 3):

That means [`attribute`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). `input[@name=button_format]` means `the input tag with the name attribute equal to button_format`.

You will need to remove the @ and quote button_format in recent versions jQuery, however. This means `@` is not backwards compatible. [So quoth the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

> **Note:** In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the “@” symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 input[@name=button_format]
```

means the input field with the name-attribute set to 'button_format', ie:

```
 <input name="button_format">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[@name=button_format]
```

This is **old selector** type.please remove if @ if you using jQuery latest
new way is

```
input[name="button_format"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were
>   previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the '@' symbol
>   from your selectors in order to make them work again.

it's a deprecated selector, you have to remove it from your code as it's no longer supported and will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

That's the OLD way of doing it.

It is the same as (and should be changed to):

```
$('input[name="button_format"]')
```

Also note the **mandatory** quotes

Answer (score 0):

Attribute as others mentioned.

My 2-cents: The notation is inspired from XPath, which also denotes (XML) attributes using an `@`